# Implement Sobel Filter in Java - Normalize values

Tags: java, image-processing, edge-detection, sobel

I want to implement Sobel Filter by myself (actual no beautiful implementation). But after doing the convolution I have no idea how to calculate the rgb values.

- Assumption: grey scaled image

  ```
  double [][] sobel_x = 
  {
      { -1, 0, 1},
      { -2, 0, 2},
      { -1, 0, 1}
  };

  double [][]    sobel_y = 
  {
      { 1, 2, 1},
      { 0, 0, 0},
      {-1, -2, 1}
  };

  for(int y=1; y<image.getHeight()-1; y++)
  {
      for(int x=1; x<image.getWidth()-1; x++)
      {
         Color a = new Color(image.getRGB(x-1, y-1));
         Color b = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y-1));
         Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(x+1, y-1));
         Color d = new Color(image.getRGB(x-1, y));
         Color e = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));
         Color f = new Color(image.getRGB(x+1, y));
         Color g = new Color(image.getRGB(x-1, y+1));
         Color h = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y+1));
         Color i = new Color(image.getRGB(x+1, y+1));

          double pixel_x =    (sobel_x[0][0] * a.getRed()) + (sobel_x[0][1] * b.getRed()) + (sobel_x[0][2] * c.getRed()) +
                              (sobel_x[1][0] * d.getRed())   + (sobel_x[1][1] * e.getRed())   + (sobel_x[1][2] * f.getRed()) +
                              (sobel_x[2][0] * g.getRed()) + (sobel_x[2][1] * h.getRed()) + (sobel_x[2][2] * i.getRed());
          double pixel_y = 
                              (sobel_y[0][0] * a.getRed()) + (sobel_x[0][1] * b.getRed()) + (sobel_x[0][2] * c.getRed()) +
                              (sobel_y[1][0] * d.getRed())   + (sobel_x[1][1] * e.getRed())   + (sobel_x[1][2] * f.getRed()) +
                              (sobel_y[2][0] * g.getRed()) + (sobel_x[2][1] * h.getRed()) + (sobel_x[2][2] * i.getRed());  

          //Here it is possible to get values between [-1020, 1020]       

          //How to going on

          //int rgb = (int) Math.sqrt(pixel_x*pixel_x+pixel_y*pixel_y);

          //int rgbAsInt = (int)(65536 * rgb + 256 * rgb + rgb);      
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

One of my ideas is to do the linear transformation. For example, the minimum pixel value in the image you got was -998 and the maximum was 1000. So you can correspond -998 to 0 and 1000 to 255, then get the relationship between the scale of (-998,1000) to the scale of (0,255) and normalize all the values between [-998,1000] to [0,255].

Answer (score 0):

The following image region has an x-axis gradient of 1:

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

Applying this filter to it --

```
-1 0 1
-2 0 2
-1 0 1
```

-- gives a result of 8. So the X and Y gradients are scaled by that factor.

You need to decide what is the maximum gradient you want to represent in the output image; call it "gr_max". The X and Y gradients should be clamped to that value:

```cxx
float gr_x, gr_y, gr_max = 16;

gr_x /= (gr_max * 8);
gr_y /= (gr_max * 8);

if (gr_x > 1)
    gr_x = 1;
if (gr_x < -1)
    gr_x = -1;

if (gr_y > 1)
    gr_y = 1;
if (gr_y < -1)
    gr_y = -1;
```

Then, assuming you want your output RGB values in the range [0, 255] --

```cxx
int pixel_x = lround((gr_x + 1) * 255/2),
    pixel_y = lround((gr_y + 1) * 255/2);
```